# Dropping outliers from dataset

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis, outliers, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing

I am trying to drop the indexes where outliers are present, but i am getting the error while dropping them. I am new in this, could you please help me in this.

Here the code:

[image]

here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Are the outliars numerical?

Answer (score 0):

As per the the documentation [pandas.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), the labels argument should be "single label or list-like". From you example, your **indexes** object contains two arrays and thus it does not work. This is what the error you are getting is telling you: "Index data must be 1-dimensional".

You have to fix the filtering of you **z** object to get a 1-dimensional list-like object containing the indices you want to drop. Without information regarding what **z** is and what you are trying to accomplish, I cannot help you out more.

Comment: z is a z score for dataset